# Return a list in loop before loop start again

Tags: python, pandas, text-processing

My code:

```py
lis2 = []
lis1 = []
for cm in comments:
    sp = cm.split()
    for s in sp:
        for tf in tfidf:
            if tf == s:
                lis2.append(tf)
            else:
                continue

lis1.append(lis2)      
print(lis1)            
data = pd.DataFrame(lis1)
```

In this code two lists:

1. `comments`: list of sentences
2. `tfidf`: a list of words.

I want to iterate every sentence (`comments`) and find any word from `tfidf` list and append it to a **new list**  `lis2`.

Also, when first sentence is finished, append `lis2` to `lis1` then go to the next sentence.

But my code just return word like this:

```py
[['custom', 'servic', 'portfolio', 'time', 'custom', 'servic', 'custom', 'servic', 'support', 'ticket', 'custom', 'servic', 'experi', 'platform', 'user', 'experi', 'account', 'portfolio', 'experi', 'user', 'experi', 'user', 'platform', 'account', 'time', 'fast', 'platform', 'custom', 'custom', 'account', 'time', 'fast', 'time', 'time', 'account', 'custom', 'servic', 'servic', 'account', 'user', 'custom', 'custom', 'account', 'time', 'account', 'user', 'time', 'account']
```

Comment: Please show us your input and exptected output data in the MWE.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] in which all of the variables you use will have sensible values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
comments = ['a1 a2 a3',  'b1 b2 b3',  'c1 c2 c3']
tfidf = ['a2', 'b1', 'b3']

lis_1 = []

for sentence in comments:
    lis_2 = []
    words = sentence.split()
    for word in words:
        if word in tfidf:
            lis_2.append(word)
    # After all words of a sentence are processed:
    lis_1.append(lis_2)

print(lis_1)
```

Output:

```
[['a2'], ['b1', 'b3'], []]
```

---

You can get the same result more succinctly using a [List Comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets):

```py
lis_1 = [list(set(sentence.split()).intersection(tfidf)) for sentence in comments]
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilize [`pandas.Series.str.findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html), then one can avoid looping.

```
comments = ["customer service emergency for service department", "client portfolio information about client spends lots of time on searching the website", "supporting customer to buy campaign ticket", "free bitcoin faucet", "experienced trading manager recruiter john cena", "user platform account deletion","Fast response platform with rock", "Login time consuming", "apple juice discount"]
comments
###
['customer service emergency for service department',
 'client portfolio information about client spends lots of time on searching the website',
 'supporting customer to buy campaign ticket',
 'free bitcoin faucet',
 'experienced trading manager recruiter john cena',
 'user platform account deletion',
 'Fast response platform with rock',
 'Login time consuming',
 'apple juice discount']
```

```
tfidf = ["customer", "account", "service", "user", "time"]
re_pat = "|".join(tfidf)
df = pd.DataFrame({'comments':comments})
```

```
output = df['comments'].str.findall(re_pat).tolist()
output
###
[['customer', 'service', 'service'],
 ['time'],
 ['customer'],
 [],
 [],
 ['user', 'account'],
 [],
 ['time'],
 []]
```